# Accessing router in ViewHelper to match routes or child_routes

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I am encountering a problem for which i have no understanding of the function of the framework  currently. I want to set up a `ViewHelper` that returns an output depending on which site i am on. If i match two specific `routes` or `child_routes`, i want the ViewHelper to output a list of links depending on that route. If i'm not on those matched routes, i want to output nothing.

Setting up a ViewHelper is pretty simply, right now my ViewHelper looks like this:

```
'factories' => array(
    'myViewHelper' => function($sm) {
        $service = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('some-doctrine-entity');
        return new \Mynamespace\View\Helper\ViewHelper($service);
    }
)
```

The output is a LIST of Links alike that

```
$this->url('someLink', array('id', $service->getId());
```

Now my problem is the `someLink` parts needs to be variable. It should be either `foo` or `bar`. Both `foo` and `bar` can have `child_routes` like `foo/index, foo/details, foo/etc` and i need to match all of them.

So my question is how to write this

```
$currentRoute = somehowGetTheCurrentRoute();
if ($currentRoute matching `foo` or `foo/child_routes`
  or is matching `bar` or `bar/child_routes`) {
    echo "im happy";
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the alternatives routes matches (if any) ?

Comment: Going by aboves example,i want the url `someLink` to be either `foo/sub` or `bar/sub` depending on if im on `foo` or `bar` or any given child_route. For this i would need to inject the matched route into the view-helper. My question is, how can i find out about the currently matched route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a method on your view helper, it assumes you have access to the service manager. The following is a way of achieving a solution of your problem:

```
//$sm is the service manager

$router=$sm->get('Router');
$request=$sm->get('Request');
$routeMatch=$router->match($request);

//get an array of the route params and their values
$routeparams=$routeMatch->getParams();

//get the matched route name
$routename=$routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();

//The previous parameters can be injected directly into the url plugin call
//$this->url($routename,$routeparams)

//the full path can also be obtained from the router
//(you can test it within a controller)
$path=$router->assemble($routeparams,$options);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this helped me quite a bit. From the `$routeName` i simply need to explode it by `/` and use jey `[0]` for the parent-route-name which is exactly what i want. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without a new match

$serviceLocator->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();